# Twitter Bootstrap content in Google Chrome is expanded all the way horizontally and not vertically

Tags: google-chrome, twitter-bootstrap, scrollspy

I have just finished my first responsive site with Twitter Bootstrap and it uses
scrollspy to scroll up and down through the five sections of the site(Home,etc,etc,etc,etc).
The site works just fine in Firefox and IE but in Chrome and Safari the content of the lower sections is expanded horizontally and not vertically like it does with Mozilla Firefox and IE.

Obviously im looking for a way to fix it,or for some detail that im missing concerning cross-browser behaviour with twitter bootstrap or html5 itself.

Comment: do you have more details or a link to your website that we can check out. or a JS fiddle?

Comment: I'm creating it local atm using bootstrap 3.0 classes,perhaps i can report which classes im using in case you know some incompatibility of em with chrome or safari

Comment: I don't know of any incompatibility. if you have code or a link to your site, Stackoverflow users might be able to help you debug it. Otherwise its pretty hard.  You can check the bootstrap issue tracker to see if someone has the same issue: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues